# Theos and Simulator - can I develop cydia tweak and test on a IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cydia, theos

I have found some great tutorials of how to install Theos to develop jailbroken apps/tweaks: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started

The problem is, I only have 1 iphone (iphone 5) which is running ios 6. If I develop such jailbreak/tweaks, can I run it on ios simulator, so that I can test on different ios version?

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit about what you're trying to do?  In other words, what the functionality of your app/tweak is?  It's possible that such a feature could be tested on a simulator, but there's lots of things that would require an actual jailbroken device for.  It's hard to say without knowing what you're building.

Comment: tweaks similar to the NCSettings, Auxo (that has something to do with the App Switcher). My iphone 5 is jailbroken, but I don't have any other idevice to test ios 5 or even ios 4. Also does Theos support ARC?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following tutorial:

http://sharedinstance.net/2013/10/running-tweaks-in-simulator/

Answer (score -1):

you can't test or run tweaks in ios simulator as it cannot be jailbroken.
jailbreak your iphone 5 and test your tweaks on a real device.
you can also send beta debs to your friends to test on other devices or ios versions.